# What is the "git stash" equivalent for Serena Dimensions?

Tags: serena

I have made some changes. I cannot use those changes now. I need to discard them for now and go back to them later when the star alignment is more favorable (e.g. when our Cobol guy has enough time to get to his half of the work).

Short of using Eclipse → Synchronize with team and manually copy pasting the contents to a scratch directory so I can do the merging later, is there any way to  "stash" changes for later?

Comment: There is no "git stash" equivalent for Serena Dimensions, is there.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `git stash` equivalent on Serena Dimensions. The poor man's way will be to store your changes temporally on a different folder or a file with different name without including it to the source controlled solution and switching back and forth as needed.

Another alternative is to use streams in order to have your changes source controlled without affecting production code; a typical scenario is to have an Integration and Main streams. But it depends on your access level to the dimension database you are using and your project needs.

A git repo can be maintained locally to have this and other git functionality on your local computer (or even small team with shared folders or a git server) since it does not interfere with Dimensions, as long as you don't store the git metadata in the dimensions managed code and vice versa. This is not a straight forward solution and will require that you know how to set a git repo and precaution on you side when delivering to the Dimension server, but it works and is really helpful if you are familiar with git workflow.

Dimensions is not so friendly as git on this kind of usages, but way more robust for larger and more controlled projects.

Comment: Unfortunately the combined use of Eclipse and Dimensions makes git interoperability very difficult (can't version multiple projects together, and some changes require coordinated commits to at least five different projects with the way we're set up.). Nice answer though!

Comment: yes, it still is plausible but the difficult to do so will outweigh the actual benefits. I have implemented the scenario of having git for the local team development for frequent commits in the local network, and the use of dimension instance to keep track of finished pieces of work in the larger global team as part of the formal processes requirements. this has was on Visual Studio.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't accept that nice answer though @badp, nice question BTW...

Answer (score 0):

Git and Dimensions work on different methodologies. Dimensions allows only to either commit a new version or discard the version, after checking out the file. As indicated above, one can still use streams or individual branches for their development work and can merge/deliver the changes later point in time, without affecting others work.